# How to use the Enter key in a modeless dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, modeless-dialog

I've been working on a WinAPI Project for university and we are asked to implement the full program in a dialog box. At first, I used a modal dialog box and everything worked fine, except that there was no icon in the taskbar for the dialog box because I created it directly on WM_CREATE and didn't make the main window visible anyway, since it isn't used.

Now I dumped the main window handle altogether and only used `CreateDialog` to create a modeless dialog, but since then I can't use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as an alternative to my default push button.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if(LOWORD(wparam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wparam) == IDC_OK) {
        [...] //doing stuff
    }
    break;
```

and this is my full main function:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE dieseInstanz, HINSTANCE vorherigeInstanz, LPSTR lpszArgument, int Fensterstil) {
    MSG Meldung;
    HWND dialog = NULL;

    dialog = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DIALOG), NULL, dialogHandler);
    if(dialog != NULL) {
        ShowWindow(dialog, SW_SHOW);
    } else {
        MessageBox(NULL, "CreateDialog returned NULL", "Warning!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    while(GetMessage(&Meldung, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Meldung);
        DispatchMessage(&Meldung);
    }
    return Meldung.wParam;
}
```

Did I just do some basic thing wrong or doesn't it work in general in the way I want to do it?

To clarify: If I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in my dialog box, I'm only getting the typical Windows notification sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message loop needs to include a call to [`IsDialogMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isdialogmessagea):

> Determines whether a message is intended for the specified dialog box and, if it is, processes the message.
>
> ...
>
> When `IsDialogMessage` processes a message, **it checks for keyboard messages and converts them into selections for the corresponding dialog box.** For example, the TAB key, when pressed, selects the next control or group of controls, and the DOWN ARROW key, when pressed, selects the next control in a group.
>
> Because the `IsDialogMessage` function performs all necessary translating and dispatching of messages, a message processed by `IsDialogMessage` must not be passed to the `TranslateMessage` or `DispatchMessage` function.

Per [Using Dialog Boxes: Creating a Modeless Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box):

> The second part of the example is the application's main message loop. **The loop includes the IsDialogMessage function to ensure that the user can use the dialog box keyboard interface in this modeless dialog box.**

This is also stated in the [`CreateDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga) documentation:

> After `CreateDialog` returns, the application displays the dialog box (if it is not already displayed) by using the `ShowWindow` function. The application destroys the dialog box by using the `DestroyWindow` function. **To support keyboard navigation and other dialog box functionality, the message loop for the dialog box must call the `IsDialogMessage` function.**

So, change your message loop to look more like this instead:

```cpp
while (GetMessage(&Meldung, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (!IsWindow(dialog) || !IsDialogMessage(dialog, &Meldung)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Meldung);
        DispatchMessage(&Meldung);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now!
I knew about this call, but I didn't think it was important in that case.